# How to group rows and list a certain columns values

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a Table that has rows of `dates` & `times`. I want to produce a list of all the times for each unique date in the `table`.

Here is the table:

```
DATE       TIME
2000-01-01 09:00:00
2000-01-01 13:00:00
2000-07-18 09:00:00
2000-07-18 13:00:00
2000-12-31 10:31:00
2000-12-31 14:17:00
2000-12-31 21:42:00
```

I would the result set to look like this:

```
2000-01-01, 09:00:00, 13:00:00
2000-07-18, 09:00:00, 13:00:00
2000-12-31, 10:31:00, 14:17:00, 21:42:00
```

Is it possible?

**Amended:**
Is it also possible to produce this result set in 1 query?

```
2000-01-01, 2000-07-18, 09:00:00, 13:00:00
2000-12-31, 10:31:00, 14:17:00, 21:42:00
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat, and `group by date(datefield)`.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. Yes, I was planning to do it in PHP but was just wondering if GROUP_CONCAT or "DISTINCT", in any way, could save me coding.

Comment: IMHO, there is no problem for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) is the solution.

Comment: the what is it best used for @Strawberry

Comment: Nothing at all - but it's just my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, GROUP_CONCAT(Time) AS Times
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar does GROUP BY also sort (ie., ORDER BY) of can I add that too?

Comment: It doesn't sort automatically, so you need to add `ORDER BY` if you need it.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Barmar. One other thing. Is it possible to GROUP_CONCAT twice in the same query? Have a look at my amended OQ

Answer (score 1):

You need GROUP_CONCAT: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Something like:

`SELECT DATE, GROUP_CONCAT(TIME) FROM tablename GROUP BY DATE`

Comment: Thank you @Grim... does GROUP BY also sort (ie., ORDER BY) of can I add that too?